# GitHub Actions not creating files when it's in a subdirectory

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to learn how to use GitHub Actions and I'm running into a small issue. When I run the code locally, the files created while `python training/train.py` is running are created in the correct folder. However, when I try to do the same thing with GitHub Actions, the files are only created when I choose to create them in the root directory rather than `/training/outputs/`. Is there a way to resolve this?

Here's my GitHub repository: https://github.com/JayThibs/github-actions-ml-template

Comment: It could be related to the user permission that execute the script. Did you try using `sudo` with `python training/train.py`? Otherwise, it could also work using `cd /training/outputs/` before executing the script, to add the files directly on this subdirectory.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did try with sudo, but it didn't work. And I'd rather figure out how to do it without have to cd since it will cause problems in the future then I want to create outputs in several different directories.

Comment: You can try to create folder here `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/training/outputs/`. If you set env `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` on your local env to empty value you will get script working both locally and on build agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out how to resolve this so I figured I should share here.

Since I am using CML (Continuous Machine Learning), I could simply include the following line in my GitHub Actions cml.yaml file:

```
cml-pr training/outputs/*
```

This is because cml does not push outputs to my code automatically.

Besides using `cml-pr`, you can also use the following github push manually:

```
git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"

git add training/outputs/*
git commit --message "Commit training outputs"
git push
```

Please keep in mind that the latter solution won't handle merge conflicts gracefully if there is a race condition between several simultaneous runs.

Since the action will push files to your repository, it will trigger another GitHub Action if your action is triggered on push. To resolve this, simply add something like [skip ci] in your commit message and GitHub will prevent an action to be triggered. You can learn more about it here: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/

0x2b3bfa0 on GitHub helped me resolve this issue, you can find our conversation here: https://github.com/iterative/cml/issues/658